# AutoComplete Works in Chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am trying to setup a search box with autocomplete. This was written by a friend of mine but he couldn't get it to work in IE either. It works great in chrome. It needs to work in IE because the people who will be using it don't have Chrome.
Here is the code:

```
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-category {
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: .4em .8em;
        margin: 1.0em 0 .4em;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $j.widget("custom.Complete", $j.ui.autocomplete, {
        _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
            var that = this,
                currentCategory = "";
            $j.each(items, function (index, item) {
                if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                    ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                    currentCategory = item.category;
                }
                that._renderItemData(ul, item);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<script>
    $j(function () {
        var data = [{
            label: "Call types",
            category: "Call Flow"
        }, {
            label: "Review",
            category: "Call Flow"
        }, {
            label: "Mikatron",
            category: "Decepticon"
        }, {
            label: "Eric Prime",
            category: "Transformer"
        }, ];

        $j("#SearchResult").Complete({
            delay: 0,
            source: data,
            appendTo: '#menu-container',
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any Ideas? I've been working on this for hours.

Comment: Can you make an online demo for it like on http://jsbin.com

Answer (score 0):

IE fails (and quite rightly so) on trailing commas in object literals.

Just after your *Eric Prime* object, you have a comma. Remove it, ie this...

```
{
    label: "Eric Prime",
    category: "Transformer"
}, ];
```

becomes this

```
{
    label: "Eric Prime",
    category: "Transformer"
}];
```

#### Update

You also have another trailing comma here...

```
$j("#SearchResult").Complete({
    delay: 0,
    source: data,
    appendTo: '#menu-container', // <-- here
});
```

Comment: Ok So I just tried that but should it be like that on all the objects or just the last one? I did it with just the last one.

Comment: @user3034943 Read my answer again; **trailing commas**

Comment: Oh sorry... Ok so I did that but it's still not working. Is there something inherently wrong with the code? I'm pretty new to coding.

Comment: @Rena Just noticed you've got another one after `appendTo: '#menu-container',`

Comment: Thanks @Phil I removed that one too. Now I'm just scouring the code to find little mistakes but I haven't been able to find anymore.